# Const must be initialized error in Microsoft Edge in for...of loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, microsoft-edge

I am using `const` with the new `for of` looping structure of JavaScript. It works fine in Chrome but in MS Edge the following code throws error:

```
for(const a of [1, 2, 3])
    console.log(a);
```

> Error: Const must be initialized

Again, works fine in chrome, edge throws error. I guess it expects const variable to have an initialization value but that's the entire job of the for isn't it?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) says edge supports the loop so browser support isn't an issue.

Comment: It is perfectly valid ES2015 code, so I presume it's the browser that should be blamed.

Comment: Yeah I guess it's an undocumented behavior.

Comment: `const` is relatively new for JavaScript.  I agree with zerkms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6, "*`const` in `for-of` loop iteration scope*" is not supported in IE and not in Edge until version 14. It's the same with `let` btw. Basic `for of` loops, and basic `const`/`let` usage do work though. MDN is not the most accurate source for browser support.

Comment: Is there any polyfill for that?

Comment: @mirik No, you cannot polyfill syntax. You need a transpiler.